# Results for query include and probably stop at july 2 2019 no matter how far back I try to go

Tags: reddit

https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?subreddit=celebs&limit=1000&sort=desc&before=1451606400000

Trying to get posts before January 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM. But the last result is from Tuesday, July 2, 2019 11:57:17 AM. Is this an issue with pushift or reddit? Thanks in advance

Comment: This feels like a very niche question, which would be best addressed to the author of the service you're using. The chances of someone stumbling on it here and having the answer are rather low.

Comment: Not too familiar with that, but a little curious that you get exactly 1000 results back.  There is some information out there about that issue already:  https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/30a7ap/does_reddit_api_limit_total_listings_returned_to/. It looks like there may be a limit to the. number of items you get back, but maybe there is a way already that by stacking your requests to include multiple timeframes / intervals.  It looking like you already have limit-1000 in your reqeust ?